# Were Kauravas 100 brothers or only 99?

Tags: mahabharata, kauravas

I get confused many times whether Dhritrashtra and Gandhari had 100 sons or just 99 sons with one daughter.

The 100<sup>th</sup> son was Yuyutsu who wasn't Gandhari's son but her maid's.

What's the truth? Were Kauravas 100 brothers or only 99?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were 100 sons of Dhritarashtra. After 100 sons, Gandhari took out Duhshala, a baby girl, from the 101st jar.

You can read it here: http://samharshbangalore.blogspot.in/2012/10/101-children-of-dhritarashtra.html

Yuyutsu was son of Dhritarashtra but not from Gandhari. He was from Sughada, a woman from Vaishya Varna. He was born on the same day as Duryodhana.

**In total Dhritarashtra had 102 children, 101 from Gandhari and 1 from Sughada.**

Comment: What about Maid' son yuyutsu ????

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava - I have updated my answer.